# Table with multirow

Tags: tables

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
    
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c ccc c cccc}
     & \multicolumn{5}{c}{N} &  \\ 
    W & 7 & 9 & 13 & 17 & 19 & 1 \\ \hline
    0.6078 & 1.0592 (4)& 1.0646 (4) & 1.0647 (6) & 1.0647 (5) & 1.0647 (5) & 1.0647 \\ 
    1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 \\ 
    1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 \\ 
    1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 \\ 
    1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 \\ 
    1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 \\ 
    1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 \\ 
    1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 \\ 
    1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 \\ 
    1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 \\ 
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{document}
```

I would like to add a column in front of the table with a label for all those 10 rows containing an S.

I know that I can do that using \multirow, but honestly I cannot figure out how.

Any help? Thanks in advance

Comment: unrelated to  multirow `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c ccc c cccc}` is wrong, use  a standard tabular or use an X column

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your answer. Could you please elaborate more about it, so I can understand what you mean?

Comment: see `texdoc tabularx`  the only thing `tabularx` does is achieve a specfied table width by adjusting the widths of X columns. You only have c columns so the package can do nothing useful

Comment: There are a few things wrong with your usage of tables. Here is a list:
    Using tabular or tabularx out of a table environment.
    Using standalone with the problem isn't specific to that document class
    See David Carliste's comment about using column specification.
    Using tabularx instead of tabular for no clear reason.
    What are those rows? > all those 10 rows containing an S.
 I can't figure out what the question is

Comment: @anis There is nothing wrong with using a tabular outside of a table environment.

Comment: @anis i am using tabularx because that is the environment used in the latex template provided by the journal, i sent my paper. I used standalone because otherwise I should send at least a couple of files to replicate the style of the journal and I thought it was not paying off. S and N are the names of two variable that I let vary: one is on the columns and one is on the rows. I acknowledge it was not clear, but I thought was not necessary to provide a deep detail. The table indicates the result of a sensitivity analysis i am carrying out on my mathematical model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For use of ˛tabularx`package you should define`\textwidth`of page layout, for example with option`varwidth=34em`
- `tabularx` table should have at least one `X` or from it derived column type
  with new column, your table have 8 columns, but you define 0 (without new column).
- it is not entirely clear how column headers should be. So I add one `\cline` below multi column cell:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth=34em]{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} c c CCCCC c @{}}
    &        & \multicolumn{5}{c}{N}                                          &         \\
    \cline{3-7}
    & W      & 7          & 9          & 13         & 17         & 19         & 1       \\
    \hline
\multirow{10}{*}{S}
    & 0.6078 & 1.0592 (4) & 1.0646 (4) & 1.0647 (6) & 1.0647 (5) & 1.0647 (5) & 1.0647  \\
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668  \\
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668  \\
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668  \\
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668  \\
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668  \\
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668  \\
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668  \\
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668  \\
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668  \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
With`tblr` of `tabularray` package you can write a bit more fancy (easy to read) table with `c` columns (similar as is used in @Pieter van Oostrum answer) with grouping of rows:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{colsep=4pt,
                 colspec={@{} *{8}{c} @{}},
                 rowsep=1pt,
                 row{even[3]} = {belowsep=1ex}
                 }
    &        & \SetCell[c=5]{c} N                                             
                          &            &            &            &            &         \\
    \cline{3-7}
tip & W      & 7          & 9          & 13         & 17         & 19         & 1       \\
    \hline
\SetCell[r=10]{c}   S
    & 0.6078 & 1.0592 (4) & 1.0646 (4) & 1.0647 (6) & 1.0647 (5) & 1.0647 (5) & 1.0647  \\
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668  \\
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668  \\
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668  \\
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668  \\
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668  \\
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668  \\
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668  \\
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668  \\
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668  \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Much clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

Like this? Note: I adapted the number of `c`s in the column spec, because it was wrong, and the `\multicolumn` to 7.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
    
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ ccc c cccc}
     & \multicolumn{7}{c}{N} \\ 
    & W & 7 & 9 & 13 & 17 & 19 & 1 \\ \hline
    \multirow{10}{*}{S} & 0.6078 & 1.0592 (4)& 1.0646 (4) & 1.0647 (6) & 1.0647 (5) & 1.0647 (5) & 1.0647 \\ 
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 \\ 
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 \\ 
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 \\ 
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 \\ 
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 \\ 
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 \\ 
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 \\ 
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 \\ 
    & 1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 \\ 
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Simple but quite effective!